# Как пишется "за()одно"?

Tags: орфография

"За одно" - вроде, пишется раздельно, но ведь его можно заменить синонимом "вместе".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наречие заодно пишется слитно. Замена на синоним используется для проверки слитного написания с НЕ существительных,  прилагательных и наречий на-О(Е), образованных от качественных прилагательных